# how to check optional variable length of number String?

Tags: regex, variables, format

What I am trying to validate something like IP address,

it maybe attach with a port or not. let me say: 10.12.1.100 and 10.12.1.100:8080 are all right.

I create something like this:

> ^10\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))([-+]?(:|\d[1,4]))$

however, it does not work for: 10.12.1.100:8080 parts.
how to implements this part ([-+]?(:|\d[1,4]))?

if I remove ([-+]?(:|\d[1,4]));it will valid 10.12.1.100 part right.

Thanks,

Comment: tcp port numbers are a 16bit number, so 0-65535. you're checking for only 4 digits.

Comment: This pattern is nasty, i'd suggest using something like what @burning_LEGION has provided. If the group structure that you currently have is required, i think i have a fix for you.

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(:\d{1,5})?$`

Answer (score 0):

Your specific pattern seems like it is doing some pretty specific IP matching, otherwise i'd suggest using something like @burning_LEGION has suggested. I'm guessing there is something specific to your scenario that goes outside normal IP parsing.

I'm only extending your current pattern because I assume you require the group structure to stay the same. otherwise I'd suggest a rewrite.

But to fix your specific example, try replacing `([-+]?(:|\d[1,4]))$` with `([-+]?(:\d{1,5}))?$`

Comment: yes, you are right, my pattern is doing specific IP matching, only port parts is standard. Thanks, both of you.